# Java catch Exception IllegalArguementsException forces me to initiate string

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Whenever I catch the exception for the integer it works fine, but when I try with the string value it wants me to initiate the string. The follow is my code so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalMath e = new LocalMath();
        Machine machine = new Machine(name);
        String name;
        int age;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name?");

        try{
        name = userInput.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception IllegalArgumentException) {
            System.out.println("Must be a character from the english alphabet!");
        }

        // System.out.println(e.add(5, 10));
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println("-------");
        System.out.println("What is your age?");

        try {
            age = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.println(age);
        } catch (Exception IllegalArgumentException) {
            System.out.println("Must be in numeric value only!");
        }


    }
}
```

And the rest of my code

```
public class Machine {
    public Machine(){

    }

    public Machine(String name){

    }

    public Machine(int age){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your String variable to null

```
        String name = null;
```

It's possible because of the try/catch block for name to get to the sysytem.out line without any value being assigned to it.  For example, if userInput.nextLine() raises an illegal argument exception, name will not be assigned a value, yet the rest of the function will execute because the exception is caught.  Anything that happens between the exception and the catch line is skipped.  Thus, the String "name" could be used before anything is assigned to it; the compiler is therefore forcing you to explicitly initiliaze it.

If you could use the variable/memory address without guaranteeing it had been set to a value first, you might find "name" holding erroneous data from the last time that memory address was used.  The compiler is guaranteeing that can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could declare `String name = null;` before you instantiate your Machine object.

However, you should instantiate the Machine object after you assign a value other than null to machine. For example, as you have it now, you're creating a machine object with a name of `null` passed into the constructor.

I would instantiate your machine like this:

```
try{
    name = userInput.nextLine();
    } catch (Exception IllegalArgumentException) {
        System.out.println("Must be a character from the english alphabet!");
    }

Machine machine = new Machine(name);
```

One more thing, I don't think `IllegalArgumentException` will prevent the user from entering a number as part of the name. `"Bob1234"` is a valid string, so you won't catch the exception in this case.

Instead, you'll have to check each character one at a time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
    if (isDigit(charAt(i))
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be in numeric value only!");
}
```

Comment: isDigit(charAt(i))    What exactly is "charAt(i)" ? I've never seen it, and it just gives me errors.